# Why are applications (like Adobe Fireworks and Appcelerator Titanium) crashing on startup?

Tags: macos, startup, crash

Closed my computer last night, went home. Opened it and it had restarted. Now when I open a couple programs such as Adobe Fireworks or Appcelerator Titanium they throw up a nasty error like below. Other programs (Chrome, Firefox, Textmate, Versions) work fine.

Any thoughts on this? I haven't owned my MacBook long so I'm not even aware of the right tools or places to look to track this down. Any help would be most appreciated. It's making it hard to get my work done :]

If it helps at all both those programs were probably open when it restarted. From the look of it I'm not sure if it's a permissions error or something? I completely re-installed on of the applications Titanium. Didn't seem to help.

```
Process: Adobe Fireworks CS5 [1044]
Path: /Applications/Adobe Fireworks CS5/Adobe Fireworks CS5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Fireworks CS5
Identifier: com.macromedia.fireworks
Version: Adobe Fireworks CS5 version 11.0.0.484 (11.0.0) Code Type: X86 (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [87]

Date/Time: 2011-02-18 09:45:47.689 -0500
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version: 6

Interval Since Last Report: 12983 sec
Crashes Since Last Report: 6
Per-App Interval Since Last Report: 325365 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report: 4
Anonymous UUID: D16EAFE7-2F04-44D4-A984-5902A6EF8943

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000b0327ff8
Crashed Thread: 7

Thread 0: 
Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0 libSystem.B.dylib
0x97dd0142 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10 1 libSystem.B.dylib
0x97dd5c46 pthread_mutex_lock + 490 2 libstdc++.6.dylib
0x91887559 __gnu_cxx::__recursive_mutex::lock() + 17 3 libstdc++.6.dylib
0x918874e6 __cxa_guard_acquire + 68 4 libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
0x91c92ab3 TTScalerInfo() + 50 5 libFontParser.dylib
0x9979a5f1 TTrueTypeScaler::CreateTrueTypeScaler() + 43 6 libSystem.B.dylib
0x97dee900 pthread_once + 82 7 libFontParser.dylib 
0x9979a575
```

Comment: Full error: http://pastebin.com/LEp2W8du

Comment: Ran rember on it to test the memory and everything passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called Apple, they suggested I re-install the OS. Originally being a PC guy that sounded like I was going to have a couple days ahead of me to backup, format, re-install my apps etc.

NOPE. With OS X you can re-install the OS and not affect any of your programs or user data/documents. So it just copied over all the core OS files and that seemed to fix everything.

Answer (score 2):

According to your crash log (thread 7 crashed) - it's trying to start up the updater and the updater is crashing attempting to read the preferences - so it's quite possible several of your preference files have been corrupted.

First thing I'd recommend is to open up Disk Utility, click on your startup drive and click Verify Disk to be sure that it's not a symptom of directory damage. If that checks out fine I'd recommend deleting the appropriate preference files from your Preferences folder (eg. `com.adobe.Fireworks.plist` from your Preferences folder) and see if that sorts things out.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'Repair Permissions' in Disk Utility, that's a generic fix for some problems so it's worth trying.  Sometimes files in `/Library/Application Support` can get corrupted during a crash, you could remove the applications causing the issues and then remove their folder from `/Library/Application Support`, then empty the trash and reinstall those apps.

Comment: Fireworks CS5 crashing on start-up, took your advice above, repaired a missing hard link using disk utility. Repaired ok. now Fireworks start fine, but only if Firefox is NOT running at the same time,

Answer (score 1):

I had a somehow similar problem before, where InDesign CS5 would crash on startup right after I installed it for the first time. It turns out that the Adobe installer program had left all of the Adobe-related Library files as read-only. Very odd behavior, indeed. According to the Adobe support forums, I was not the only one to have had this problem.

My suggestion is to open a Finder window and go to a path that will look very similar to:

```
/Users/YOUR-USER/Library/Preferences/Adobe InDesign/Version 7.0.
```

Of course, you must replace **YOUR-USER** with your user account and **Adobe InDesign** with whatever Adobe program you are experiencing problems with. Also, your version number might be different. On this example, InDesign CS5 is Version 7.0, but that might be different for your version. Browsing to the Adobe-named folders within your Library, it should not be hard to find which is the right one.

Once you have found and selected your folder, open the File menu, and then select File/Get Info. On the last pane you will find the Sharing and Permissions options. Expand this pane, unlock the settings for this folder by clicking on the lock button, then press the plus sign (+) button. Add your user account and assign it Reading and Writing privileges.

Reopen your Adobe program and it should be able to start succesfully. The problem is most likely that it is not being able to write to its settings files within the Library special folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Fireworks CS5. After starting the program, it tries to build the menu structure, but freezes while doing that.

The thing that worked for me was to remove the folder 'Macromedia' from `/Users/YOUR-USER/Library/Preferences/`. The only trouble with that folder is that it will reincarnate quite fast...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution that someone else posted over at Adobe:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3929927

It looks like the issue is that if you've *ever* installed flashfirebug, it will create a flashfirebug.cfg (possibly mm.cfg in an older version?), and this will prevent the launch of a few programs.  This seems to be also what Peter/patrix is saying above.

Fireworks CS5.1 will crash on launch; Extension Manager (I've heard) has problems launching; and it would make sense that the Updater might fail to launch as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are near an Apple store, book an appointment with a Genius.

That's what they are there for. I've found the experience faultless on the few occasions I have needed them. This is Apple: there IS a difference.